# Python: get 2nd idxmax from nsmallest if there is a draw

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `DataFrame` as below. What I want to get is mininim 1st, 2nd, ... , n `Value` for each `Article` and know which `Name` each `Value` originates.

```py
df
   Article  Name  Value
0     A_01  P_01    360
1     A_03  P_01    625
2     A_01  P_07    360
3     A_01  P_09    370
4     A_02  P_09    847
5     A_03  P_09    685
6     A_03  P_18    650
7     A_02  P_22    935
8     A_03  P_22    625
9     A_02  P_25    750
10    A_03  P_25    600
11    A_01  P_26    500
12    A_02  P_26    750
13    A_03  P_26    600
14    A_01  P_33    480
15    A_03  P_33    750
```

I am using this code to find `n minimum value` and `n minimum name` of each `Article`.
First I've pivoted my `df` to get:

```py
list_articles = df['Article'].drop_duplicates()
list_names = list(df['Name'].drop_duplicates())

pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Article', columns='Name', values='Value').reset_index()
```

```py
pivot_df
Name Article   P_01   P_07   P_09   P_18   P_22   P_25   P_26   P_33
0       A_01  360.0  360.0  370.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  500.0  480.0
1       A_02    NaN    NaN  847.0    NaN  935.0  750.0  750.0    NaN
2       A_03  625.0    NaN  685.0  650.0  625.0  600.0  600.0  750.0
```

Then I've runned lambda function to find `minimum_value` and corresponding `minimum_name`:

```py
for i in range(1, 4):  # minimum 3
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Value'] = pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(i).max())
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Name'] = pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(i).idxmax())
```

which gives me another 6 columns:

```py
pivot_df
Name Article   P_01   P_07  ...  Min_2_Name  Min_3_Value  Min_3_Name
0       A_01  360.0  360.0  ...        P_01        370.0        P_09
1       A_02    NaN    NaN  ...        P_25        847.0        P_09
2       A_03  625.0    NaN  ...        P_25        625.0        P_01
```

and after filtering only to those columns which interest me:

```py
ColsToKeep = [x for x in pivot_df.columns.to_list() if x not in list_names]
ColsToKeep = [x for x in ColsToKeep if x[:3] == 'Min']
ColsToKeep.sort()
ColsToKeep = ['Article'] + ColsToKeep

final_df = pivot_df[ColsToKeep]
```

I get `final df`:

```py
final_df
Name Article Min_1_Name  Min_1_Value Min_2_Name  Min_2_Value  Min_3_Name Min_3_Value
0       A_01       P_01        360.0       P_01        360.0        P_09       370.0
1       A_02       P_25        750.0       P_25        750.0        P_09       847.0
2       A_03       P_25        600.0       P_25        600.0        P_01       625.0
```

whole code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
      [['A_01', 'P_01', 360],
       ['A_03', 'P_01', 625],
       ['A_01', 'P_07', 360],
       ['A_01', 'P_09', 370],
       ['A_02', 'P_09', 847],
       ['A_03', 'P_09', 685],
       ['A_03', 'P_18', 650],
       ['A_02', 'P_22', 935],
       ['A_03', 'P_22', 625],
       ['A_02', 'P_25', 750],
       ['A_03', 'P_25', 600],
       ['A_01', 'P_26', 500],
       ['A_02', 'P_26', 750],
       ['A_03', 'P_26', 600],
       ['A_01', 'P_33', 480],
       ['A_03', 'P_33', 750]],
      columns=['Article', 'Name', 'Value'])

list_articles = df['Article'].drop_duplicates()
list_names = list(df['Name'].drop_duplicates())

pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Article', columns='Name', values='Value').reset_index()

for i in range(1, 4):
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Value'] = pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(i).max())
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Name'] = pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(i).idxmax())

ColsToKeep = [x for x in pivot_df.columns.to_list() if x not in list_names]
ColsToKeep = [x for x in ColsToKeep if x[:3] == 'Min']
ColsToKeep.sort()
ColsToKeep = ['Article'] + ColsToKeep

final_df = pivot_df[ColsToKeep]
```

Finally, what is my problem? If you look closely, you'll notice that `Min_1_Value` and `Min_2_Value` are the same (which is correct), but `Min_1_Name` and `Min_2_Name` are also the same which is not correct. Why? Because in the original data there are 2 names with the same values for the same articles so it's a draw. My code is looking for the name of min_n by index of min_n_value so if there is more than 1 match, it takes it not taking into consideration possibility of a draw. But how to get the `Min_2_Name` correctly assigned for the one which is not `Min_1_Name`? It can be selected alphabetically, doesn't matter. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your solution should be simplify - first [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by 2 columns:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Article','Value'])
print (df)
   Article  Name  Value
0     A_01  P_01    360
2     A_01  P_07    360
3     A_01  P_09    370
14    A_01  P_33    480
11    A_01  P_26    500
9     A_02  P_25    750
12    A_02  P_26    750
4     A_02  P_09    847
7     A_02  P_22    935
10    A_03  P_25    600
13    A_03  P_26    600
1     A_03  P_01    625
8     A_03  P_22    625
6     A_03  P_18    650
5     A_03  P_09    685
15    A_03  P_33    750
```

Then create counter Series by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and filter for top3 values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), add to `MultiIndex` and reshape by 
[`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` in columns by `f-string`s:

```
g = df.groupby('Article').cumcount().add(1)
mask = g < 4
df = df[mask].set_index(['Article',g[mask]]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'Min_{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
df = df.reset_index()

print (df)
  Article Min_1_Name  Min_1_Value Min_2_Name  Min_2_Value Min_3_Name  \
0    A_01       P_01          360       P_07          360       P_09   
1    A_02       P_25          750       P_26          750       P_09   
2    A_03       P_25          600       P_26          600       P_01   

   Min_3_Value  
0          370  
1          847  
2          625
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by replacing previous smallest by NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
      [['A_01', 'P_01', 360],
       ['A_03', 'P_01', 625],
       ['A_01', 'P_07', 360],
       ['A_01', 'P_09', 370],
       ['A_02', 'P_09', 847],
       ['A_03', 'P_09', 685],
       ['A_03', 'P_18', 650],
       ['A_02', 'P_22', 935],
       ['A_03', 'P_22', 625],
       ['A_02', 'P_25', 750],
       ['A_03', 'P_25', 600],
       ['A_01', 'P_26', 500],
       ['A_02', 'P_26', 750],
       ['A_03', 'P_26', 600],
       ['A_01', 'P_33', 480],
       ['A_03', 'P_33', 750]])

df.columns=['Article','Name','Value']
list_articles = df['Article'].drop_duplicates()
list_names = list(df['Name'].drop_duplicates())
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Article', columns='Name', values='Value').reset_index()
for i in range(1, 4):
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Value'] = pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(1).max())
    indices=pivot_df[list_names].T.apply(lambda y: y.nsmallest(1).idxmax())
    pivot_df[f'Min_{i}_Name'] = indices
    for i,x in enumerate(indices):
        pivot_df[x][i]=np.nan

ColsToKeep = [x for x in pivot_df.columns.tolist() if x not in list_names]
ColsToKeep = [x for x in ColsToKeep if x[:3] == 'Min']
ColsToKeep.sort()
ColsToKeep = ['Article'] + ColsToKeep

final_df = pivot_df[ColsToKeep]
final_df
```